# Ruby on Rails changing time zones for application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, timezone, mongoid

My application has been running for over 6 months in the UTC time zone. This means all ActiveRecord and MongoDB objects have been created in the UTC time zone. Curious enough, if I go ahead and change the applicable setting in application.rb:

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

Will this convert the records that were created in UTC to the EST time zone? What about the MongoDB records? (I use Mongoid as my Ruby driver). Is it as simple as flipping a switch in application.rb and that's it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveRecord will store everything in UTC regardless of what `config.time_zone` says; I'm having a hard time finding an authoritative reference on this, the best I've found so far is the [`ActiveRecord::Timestamp`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html) docs. [MongoDB should also be storing everything in UTC](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#date):

> **Date**
>
> BSON Date is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970). The official BSON specification refers to the BSON Date type as the UTC *datetime*.

So nothing in your databases should change or need to be changed. The `config.time_zone` setting is only used in the Rails side of things, it has nothing to do with what time zone is used inside your databases so you shouldn't have anything to worry about.